# Why does the conversion HSV to BGR and BGR to HSV doesn't match?

Tags: colors, space, hsv, bgr

what could probably be the reason why a conversion HSV to BGR and the reverse operation BGR to HSV doesn't match?

Comment: You should give us an example and what formula you used. Your question is too generic. causes: lack of precision (use floating point), different definition of BGR or HSV (yeah there are different definition, you hsould take compatible conversions)

Comment: You'll have to give us a little bit more to go on. Do you have a specific instance that's not working properly? Are you doing this by hand, or implementing it in code, or with some library? Please add a [mre] to your question.

Comment: Try which black, then white, then red. Usually you get very good hints where it is the problem (you know what are the expected values both on HSV, and RGB)